# Stream content missing from 2010 - FB bug?

Tags: database, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've got an app with read_stream permissions (along with a bunch of others).  I'm querying FB for a user's stream and paging back through their history, with the goal of capturing all of their posts, along with posts they're tagged in.

This works fine until 2010, when my app stops receiving posts from the user, and only receives posts the user is tagged in.  For example, I have a post that I wrote on August 14, 2010. It's visible on my timeline AND on my timeline from the App's perspective, but it does not appear in my query results.

I first saw this problem with my FQL queries, but I can replicate with even a simple Graph API call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=token&until=1281893856 (August 15, 2010)
```

Shows only posts from other people, never my posts.  Conversely,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=token&until=1319048043 (Right Now)
```

Shows recent posts by me.

**Update**: Older URLs work as well.  e.g.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=token&until=1192210656 (October 12, 2007)
```

Shows my first posts on Facebook after joining.  It seems like this only affects content around 2010.

Any ideas, anyone?  Anybody seeing anything similar?  I'm losing my mind here.

Comment: Any special "privacy setting" set on that particular post?

Comment: Nope, default settings, and it's more than one post, it's months' worth of posts.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I also have this problem!